# Trigger could not be executed due to table mutating

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

I want to know what is the problem for this issue whereby it kept on showing me this error when I execute my stored procedure. My goal is to before updating data into my table using my stored procedure, I want to check errors from trigger that the user input

```
SQL> exec PRC_PAY_TRIP(1031,2031,'Cash',200)
BEGIN PRC_PAY_TRIP(1031,2031,'Cash',200); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table TEST.PAYMENT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "TEST.TRG_PAYMENT_VALIDATION", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TEST.TRG_PAYMENT_VALIDATION'
ORA-06512: at "TEST.PRC_PAY_TRIP", line 45
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I went to search the problem and one of the solution was simply change 'after' to 'before' within the trigger

"before update on payment"  --> like this

but it still wouldn't work

STORED PROCEDURE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_PAY_TRIP(CUST_ID IN NUMBER,PAYMENT_ID IN NUMBER,PAYMENT_TYPE IN VARCHAR2,AMT_PAY IN NUMBER)AS


v_paymentstatus VARCHAR2(15) := 'Paid';
v_temppaymentid NUMBER(4) := PAYMENT_ID;
v_truenumber NUMBER(10);


no_null_on_custID EXCEPTION;
no_null_on_payID EXCEPTION;
invalid_paymentid EXCEPTION;
invalid_paymenttype EXCEPTION;
invalid_paymentamt EXCEPTION;


BEGIN

v_truenumber := v_temppaymentid-1000;


IF CUST_ID < 0
THEN
RAISE no_null_on_custID;
END IF;

IF PAYMENT_ID < 0
THEN
RAISE no_null_on_payID;
END IF;

IF CUST_ID ^= v_truenumber THEN
RAISE invalid_paymentid;
END IF;

IF PAYMENT_TYPE ^= 'Cash' AND PAYMENT_TYPE ^= 'E-Wallet' THEN
RAISE invalid_paymenttype;
END IF;

IF AMT_PAY < 0 THEN
RAISE invalid_paymentamt;
END IF;



UPDATE Payment
SET paymenttype = PAYMENT_TYPE,paymentdate = TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD/MON/YYYY'), paymentstatus = v_paymentstatus
where paymentid = PAYMENT_ID;


EXCEPTION

WHEN no_null_on_custID then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Customer ID');

WHEN no_null_on_payID then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Payment ID');

WHEN invalid_paymenttype then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You can either choose Cash or E-Wallet only!');

WHEN invalid_paymentid then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Payment id is not yours, just add 1000 from your Customer ID and that will be your Payment ID');

WHEN invalid_paymentamt then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Amount pay cannot be negative value!');

END;
/
```

TRIGGER

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trg_payment_validation
 before update on payment
 for each row

DECLARE

 v_paymentstatus payment.paymentstatus%type;
 v_customerid booking.customerid%type;
 v_paymentid payment.paymentid%type;
 v_paymentamt payment.paymentamount%type;

BEGIN 

select po.paymentstatus into v_paymentstatus
 from payment po
 where po.paymentid = :new.paymentid;


select po.paymentamount into v_paymentamt
 from payment po
where po.paymentid = :new.paymentid;

if SQL%FOUND then
    if v_paymentstatus = 'Paid' then
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
        -20950,
        'You already paid for your trip, have a nice day'
      );
    elsif v_paymentamt < :old.paymentamount then
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
        -20950,
        'Insufficient amount entered, pls pay the exact amount'
      );
    end if;
  end if;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Why are you posting essentially the same question under different account?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68891392/trigger-if-else-statement-error-not-being-raised-oracle-pl-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking data in the same row as you are updating then don't use a `SELECT` statement, instead check the `:NEW` and `:OLD` bind variables:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trg_payment_validation
  before update on payment
  for each row
BEGIN 
  if :OLD.paymentstatus = 'Paid' then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
      -20950,
      'You already paid for your trip, have a nice day'
    );
  elsif :NEW.paymentamount < :old.paymentamount then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
      -20950,
      'Insufficient amount entered, pls pay the exact amount'
    );
  end if;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi MTO,  the code that you give has executed successfully but
i think my error command has confuses you therefore i would like to change

from this error 
'You already paid for your trip, have a nice day'

to this error
'You cannot pay the fares as you already paid before this, have a nice day'

Comment: @TZEJIANTING Then just change the text when you implement it in your application.

Comment: Oh my, it workss, thank youuu! but may i know why is the second error could not be raised? Ive input the payment amount lower than the amount needed within the payment table but it doesnt raise that error in fact it staight away continue with the procedure. which means it updated the specific row even though the amount entered is insufficient! PLease help me

Comment: Which column tells you the amount needed? I am assuming that `paymentamount` is the amount that the user has currently paid and your trigger would check that they are not updating the row with a lower amount than they have already paid but it does not check that the amount paid has any relationship to the total due. I do not know your tables so I cannot answer as to what it should be; you will either need to provide more information or work it out yourself.

Comment: The paymentamount column, for example within table it stated 80.00 which means if the user enter anything lower than that amount , errors within trigger would be raised but it didnt!

Comment: @TZEJIANTING It appears to be working [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0fd6c624a15cacd4588db9abc1ddc1d2).

Comment: but im not sure why my ps/sql proceed with the stored procedure even though it suppose to show errors from the trigger!

Comment: @TZEJIANTING You are not updating the `PAYMENTAMOUNT` in the procedure so the second error in the trigger will never fire.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much MTO, i had more understanding on triggers now! and the problem has been solved! thank you